# Find JsonObject in JsonArray (javax.json.JsonArray) By Key or Value Using Java 8 Lambas

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I haven't been able to find a concise/up-to-date answer on how to use Java 8 Lambdas to quickly locate a `JsonObject` in a `JsonArray` (`javax.json.JsonArray`). All the answers about loops, which are too verbose.

Suppose I have

```
JsonArray answersArray  = ...
```

The array is

```
[   {
        "activityQuestionId": "875",
        "questionType": "STARTTIME",
        "answer": "12:45am"
    }, {
        "activityQuestionId": "876",
        "questionType": "ENDTIME",
        "answer": "1:00am"
    }, 
    ...
    {
        "activityQuestionId": "SPECIAL",
        "questionType": "DROPDOWN",
        "answer": "756", 
        "extra": "SPECIAL/EXTRA"
    }
]
```

Normally, I can do

```
JsonArray answersArray  = ...
JsonObject obj1 = answersArray.getJsonObject(1); // This brings back 2nd object 
String str = obj1.getString("answer"); // This brings back 1:00am answer in 2nd object
```

I need to do the following:

- Find By Key: Locate `JsonObject` having the key `"extra"`. Only 1 object has it (the last), so that's the one I should get.
- Find By Value of Some Key: Locate `JsonObject` having `"activityQuestionId": "SPECIAL"`. The same last object should be returned.

`JsonArray`: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArray.html

Comment: Which part of writing the stream code is troubling you? Since `JsonArray` is a `List<JsonValue>`, you can call `stream()` on it. To locate something, you'd use `filter(...)` and `findFirst()`. Those are all fairly simple, and there are many examples of their use on the web, so what have you tried, and how is that not working for you?

Comment: *"haven't been able to find [...] how to use Java 8 Lambdas to quickly locate [...]"* Really? Web search: [`java 8 lambda find in list`](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+8+lambda+find+in+list)

Comment: The difficulty is with `filter` you're not getting the key here that you can test. You can do get("stringConstant") but you can't easily get a key set and iterate over it.

Comment: *"you're not getting the key here that you can test"* Getting the key is your job: `.filter(obj -> "bar".equals(obj.get("foo")))` will filter out all objects that don't have a `foo` and objects where `foo` is not `"bar"`

Comment: No, you can't do `get("foo")` on a `JsonValue`. That's not a supported operation.

Comment: Since you know the array contains objects, use a **cast**, *exactly* like you would if you wrote the code using an old foreach loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution

```
List<JsonValue> objects1 = answersArray.stream().filter(obj -> 
            ((JsonObject)obj).getString("extra") != null).collect(Collectors.toList());

List<JsonValue> objects2 = answersArray.stream().filter(obj ->      
            "SPECIAL".equals(((JsonObject)obj).getString("activityQuestionId")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This should work

```
 final Optional<Object> extra = IntStream.range(0, jsonArray.length())
                .mapToObj(i -> getJsonObject(jsonArray, i))
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .map(this::getObject)
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .findFirst();
     //if extra.isPresent() then do extra.get() to get the value
    }

   //Instead of returning a generic type try to return specific type
   //Better Exception handling
    private Object getObject(JSONObject entry) {
        try {
            return entry.get("extra");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private JSONObject getJsonObject(JSONArray jsonArray, int i) {
        try {
            return jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This is not a complete solution. This should give you some idea about how to approach. You should check out how to handle exceptions inside lambdas if you want to use lamdas for this kinda code, because json processing throws lots of checked exceptions. And you cannot just throw those from inside lambdas, you need to handle it.

You need to think if using Streams is a good approach for this scenario or if its a over kill.

Answer (score 0):

Locate JsonObject having key "extra"

```
JsonObject extraKeyJsonObject = value.stream()
        .map(JsonValue::asJsonObject)
        .filter(jo -> jo.containsKey("extra"))
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(null);// or something else
```

Locate JsonObject having "activityQuestionId": "SPECIAL"

```
JsonObject activityIdSpecialJsonObject = value.stream()
        .map(JsonValue::asJsonObject)
        .filter(jo -> "SPECIAL".equals(jo.getString("activityQuestionId", null)))
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(null);// or something else
```

Answer (score -2):

Try This ...

```
JsonObject jsonObject= answersArray.getJsonObject(1) // 1 is the second index in the json array
String activityQuestionId= jsonObject.getString("activityQuestionId");
String questionType= jsonObject.getString("questionType");
```

Comment: How is this an answer to how to "Find By Key" and "Find By Value"?

Comment: In FInd By Key, You could use this code `if (jsonObject.containsKey("extra"))`

In Find By Value, Loop into each jsonObject and check if there's a value `SPECIAL`

Comment: And how does that apply to anything in your answer?